# Files I cannot delete after git rebase

Tags: git, github

I did a git rebase on my repository. I rebased many commits.

I now have these files in my local directory that I cannot delete.

When I try to delete them my computer says that they cannot be found.

EDIT:
I unfortunately cannot recall everything that I did. I will try my best to detail what I did.
I first did a number of git rebases so that I have a cleaner history. I was able to obtain a few commits from many. 
I used the fixup method to squash my commits together. 
Then I pushed to my remote repo.
After everything I realized that I had accidently fixed up a commit that I wanted. 
So I did a git reset --hard from my reflog in to go back to a state where I had the commit I wanted. 
After that I did a git rebase on the whole thing again and kept the commit that I had. merge queue prediction with constant buffer was one of the commit that I kept but I reworded. 
Lastly, I pushed to my remote repo again.

Please let me know anything else that will help.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: This has happened once to me before, and I don't even recall how I resolved it.  In any case, you probably want to tell us exactly what steps you took to end up in this situation.  Using rebase correctly should not leave you in this state.

Comment: Those files should be untracked. If no changes were made after the rebase (all work is committed) try `git clean` which removes all untracked files from working directory.

Comment: You my friend, are a genius :). I just had to use git clean -f. Thank you :D

Comment: I ll post that as an aswer.

Comment: I know of two possible scenarios that can lead to this. A program, such as Antivirus, is holding a handle to these files open, but they have been requested deleted by a program. As such, Windows considers the files as deleted, even though they still appear in directory listings (for as long as Antivirus or other programs keep them open). A computer restart should fix that. The other scenario is that you're too deep in directory paths. Since the filenames are somewhat long, if the total path (directory + file names) is >260 characters, some parts of Windows cannot handle this correctly.

Comment: For the second scenario, try renaming the parent directory to "x" temporarily, see if you can then delete the files before renaming the directory back.

Answer (score 0):

Files like these remain as temporary files in the working tree (mostly) after resolved conflicts. These files are untracked by git. To remove those files, one can either remove them manually, or by `git clean` command. To ensure, nothing goes wrong, the procedure should be done in two steps:

1. Ensure no files are uncommited in the directory (all work is commited) - only rubbish (untracked files) are left in the working directory.
2. Use `git clean` command to clean all untracked files.